# value Change Listener is not calling in h:selectOneMenu component

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces, icefaces

this is my .XHTML file

```
 <h:form id="limit" styleClass="edit">
    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{limitHome.condition[0]}" style="width:146px;"  
     valueChangeListener="#{limitMasterController.conditionValueChangeListener()}" >
                <a:support event="onchange" reRender="mapdMdlPnl" limitToList="true" />
                <f:selectItems  value="#{limitHome.conditionFech}"/>
    </h:selectOneMenu>
</h:form>
```

and i am calling one method in .java class

public void conditionValueChangeListener(ValueChangeEvent event)
{

```
    System.out.println("cal :::::::::: ");

    String oldValue = (String) event.getOldValue();
    String newValue = (String) event.getNewValue();

    System.out.println("oldValueoldValueoldValueoldValueoldValue = > " + oldValue);
    System.out.println("newValuenewValuenewValuenewValuenewValue ==> " + newValue);
```

}

here i amy cod but i am not getting any single sysout. so i dont know where is a problem..

Comment: yes i got it .. thank you.. i has to write valueChangeListener="#{limitMasterController.conditionValueChangeListener}" insted of valueChangeListener="#{limitMasterController.conditionValueChangeListener()}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible reasons I noticed are:

- `a:support`, shouldn't it be
  `a4j:support`
- your call should be
  `valueChangeListener="#limitMasterController.conditionValueChangeListener}"`
  without braces.